# Should entity properties be represented by a value object?

Tags: entity, value-object

I read somewhere that one should be generous in creating value objects for entity properties that are part of the class API.

So I did that with my project entity/aggregate, but it still looks weird:

```
        return new Project(
                new ProjectId( $project->post->ID ),
                new DestinationNumber( $DestinationNumber ),
                new AssociatedClient( $associatedClientId ),
                new NotificationForm( $NotificationFormName ),
                new Status( $project->post->ID, $StatusFieldsAndValues ),
                new Settings( $project->post->ID, $SettingsFieldsAndValues ) 
            );
```

All these entity properties have getters (like getStatus), which means they are relevant for other services or repositories. So, should I make the effort to create a value object in any case, or is there a line somewhere? My example seems like overkill.

Comment: I haven't seen anything like that before.  Is it possible you misunderstood what you read "somewhere?"  That said, having six `new` keywords in the same place is not exactly unprecedented; the problem here is that you need to have a good understanding of ***why.***

Comment: Make `$project->post->ID` be an instance of `ProjectId` instead of a primitive, then you have one less thing to new here.

Comment: I probably misunderstood the concept, since I'm just getting into the whole idea of entities and value objects. From the book: "In DDD, types like that [string, DateTimeImmutable, UuidInterface] are usually avoided in the domain and are replaced by value objects. That approach [...] adds a lot of meaning to the code. You don't have to wrap every single value into a value object, but the public API of your domain objects should use them generously."

Comment: Similar: [Value Objects, when to create one/](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2017/06/15/value-objects-when-to-create-one/)

Answer (score 3):

**Should?** No.

**Could?** Yes.

That's the short answer.

While [primitive obsession](https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession) is definitely something you should look into and avoid, keep in mind that anything that can be done can also be overdone.

I would argue that you can just as easily fall into the trap of "value object obsession", where you end up wrapping every single scalar value needlessly in a wrapper of its own.

Where you draw the line on *reasonable* value object use is very contextual, there is no universal one-size-fits-all answer here.

Comment: I'd suggest maybe rather than no for Should?

Comment: @jk. You've fallen prey to a logical fallacy  (1) "Could" = optional = maybe (2) "Should" = required = must. (3) The logical opposite of "should" (i.e. the "no") means "you're not _required_ to", it  does not mean "you're not allowed to" (4)  The inverse of "could" (i.e. a "no") means "you are not allowed/able to".

Comment: Depends on the context. [RFC 2119](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2119) (quite often used for technical documents) specifies different meaning, so does my native (Czech) language, where meanings of "should" and "must" greatly differentiate, while you mention them to be equal.

Comment: @Andy: AH, the "joys" of humans and their vague semantics :) Strictly logically, "should not" means "not required", but you are indeed correct that humans often infer this to mean "not allowed" or "not advised", e.g. "you should not eat that poisonous berry". But I do think that in the context of comparing "should? no. could? _yes_", it's clear that I'm sticking to the logical expression, not the semantically vauge one.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to answer my own question, I would say that properties of an entity should be represented by a value object if there is any business logic attached to them, ie. a project phone number should be of a valid format, instead of just a string. Which doesn't mean that this is the only case where a value should be wrapped into an object.

Based on http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/01/19/from-primitive-obsession-to-domain-modelling/.

Comment: Just so I understand where you're going with this, can you tell me what you think "value object" means?

Comment: A value (and it's invariants) that is represented by an object.

Comment: Ok.  Well, I looked up "Value Object" on Wikipedia, and it says that a Value Object is an object having *value semantics for equality;* that is, if I compare two such objects for equality, the result of that comparison is based on the *value* of the object, and not the *reference* to that object.  [Fowler agrees with this definition](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html).  In languages like C# and Java, you can make any object a "value object" by implementing an "equatable" or "comparable" interface.

Comment: [Seeman's article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/01/19/from-primitive-obsession-to-domain-modelling/) is interesting, and it does provide some insight into where one might choose to put their business logic, but I don't see how that has much to do with something being a "value object."

Comment: In the current context, I relate to this: "Instead of string, you can (and should) make user name a type. That type can encapsulate all the business rules in a single place, without violating DRY. This is what is meant by a Domain Model. In Domain-Driven Design terminology, a primitive like a string or a number can be turned into a Value Object." I fail to understand the semantics for equality; I have not yet seen a case where 2 Value Objects of the same type where being compared - which doesn't mean much as I'm just starting with this.

Comment: When two reference variables are compared for equality in C# or Java, the *references* to the two objects are compared.  Essentially, *the two variables must be pointing to the same object.*  If you're comparing two strings for equality, this is almost certainly not what you want, which is why C# automatically confers *value semantics* on strings.  Seeman is mostly discussing *checking the validity* of a string, e.g. a telephone number or social security number.  Making a telephone number an actual object allows you to encapsulate the validation rules for a telephone number inside that object.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I thought I read quite a bit about Value Objects in PHP, but I completely overlooked the equality aspect.

Comment: PHP doesn't have the equatable interface, but it has the '==' operator which returns true if the member fields of the objects referenced to by the two references are equal(ish), and the '===' operator which instead returns true only if the two references are identical, i.e. refer to the same object instance.

Comment: As I understand the term 'value object' it describes the semantics of the object as understood by a programmer. It's not a purely technical matter that could be detected by a static analysis tool.  Eric Evans defines it in Domain Driven Design (p. 98) as "An object that represents a descriptive aspect of the domain with no conceptional identity is called a value object. Value objects are instantiated to represent elements of the design that we care about only for what they are, not who or which they are." He says that value objects should be made immutable.